# How to set useState by checking User data in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, conditional-statements

I can't seem to figure out how to set useState after querying Firebase.
I need BOX to be equal to "public URL" for everyone except for admin.

```
import { auth } from "../firebase";
...
  const [BOX, setBox] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {
if (auth.currentUser?.email === "admin@yahoo.com") {
  setBox("https://admin/link");
   } else {
     setBox("https://public/link");
   }
 },[auth]);
```

Errors are always different. Sometimes it returns "...empty link", sometimes "network request failed". Sometimes it does show the correct data, but it runs into one of the errors when I refresh the screen.

Here is my firebase file

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import 'firebase/firestore';
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
...
};

// Initialize Firebase

let app;
if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
    app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
} else {
    app = firebase.app()
}

const auth = firebase.auth();
const dbFirebase = app.firestore();

export {auth, dbFirebase};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use hook inside an if statement...

```
 const [box, setBox] = useState('');
  
useEffect(() => {
    if (auth.currentUser?.email === "admin@yahoo.com") {
      setBox("https://admin/link");
       } else {
         setBox("https://public/link");
       }
 },[auth]);
```

Comment: Thank for helping. It gives me "Network request failed" error. I eddied the question

Comment: Can you please check ✅ my solution for the useEffect and I will send a solution for the network issue on a separate answer.

Comment: Check in your package.json file for your firebase version... eg: ```"firebase": "^9.6.8",```

Comment: I changed from "firebase": "8.2.3" to "firebase": "^9.6.8"... same error "Network request failed".

Comment: @Slava check the setup in my 2nd answer

Answer (score 0):

For firebase 9 you will need to configure it like below:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'

const firebaseConfig = {...}

initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

export const auth = getAuth()
```